# How to operate non-standard-evaluation in correct manner for summarize{dplyr}

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to pass variables to 'summarize' by way of non-standard-evaluation approach (see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-expressions).

My script is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(pryr)
x2<-data.frame(x=runif(1000,1,10),y=rnorm(1:1000))
y2<-group_by(x2,x)
field2<-"x"
z<-substitute(summarize(y2,check=sum(x)),list(x=as.name(field2)))
eval(quote(z),parent.frame())
```

But the output is not a dataframe as I supposed but a string:

```
>eval(quote(z),parent.frame())
summarize(y2, check = sum(x))
```

I am a little bit confused with non-standard-evaluation although I have looked through a number of examples.

Could you specify what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Let's begin with: What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Don't `quote` `z`, or it won't get evaluated.

Comment: @ Richard Scriven
I want to pass to 'summarize' column names not explicitly but by a variable. The output should be a dataframe.

Comment: As alistaire pointed out, `eval(z,parent.frame())` should work. Does that answer you question?

Comment: @MrFlick
You are true. it is necessary just to remove 'quote'.